# PPQ QAT for Yolo

Tags: pytorch, yolov5, loss

Is there anyone who used to implement QAT in PPQ for YOLO?

I got some problem while rewritting trainer.py for yolov5.

The loss is decreasing during the training process, but the mAP is very low.

would anyone like to share the source code for learining?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.